# I want to change my data into a good format to plot it with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I calculated an average per hour and I want to display the information. But the data does not come in a good format to be displayed by ggplot

I have just begin learning `R` since one week

```r
df=data.frame(c("110f","118d","122f"),"5"=c(38.73061,38.95500,38.51979),"6"=c(39.06633,38.93163,39.16500),
              "7"=c(38.91837,38.80707,39.5400),"8"=c(38.93673,38.87778,38.98317))
df=t(df, by="Id")
rownames(df)=c("110f","110f","110f","110f","110f")
```

The data frame i want to have

```
# 110f  38.73061    5
# 110f  39.06633    6
# 110f  38.91837    7
# 110f  38.93673    8
# 118d  38.95500    5
# 118d  38.93163    6
# 118d  38.80707    7
# 118d  38.87778    8
# 122f  38.51979    5     
# 122f  39.16500    6
# 122f  39.54000    7
# 122f  38.98317    8
```

Comment: Convert to long format

Comment: You should rather provide (expected) data with code than with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

An option is `gather` into 'long' format and then use `ggplot`

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
gather(df, key, val, - ID) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x = ID, y = val, fill = key)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

---

Also, in `base R`, we can use `matplot`

```
matplot(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df[-1]), df$ID), type = 'l')
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("110f", "118d", 
"122f"), class = "factor"), X5 = c(38.73061, 38.955, 38.51979
), X6 = c(39.06633, 38.93163, 39.165), X7 = c(38.91837, 38.80707, 
39.54), X8 = c(38.93673, 38.87778, 38.98317)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: With geom_bar, I see the bars that are displayed but I would like to have the curves so I changed geom_bar to geom_line but I only see Id and average temperatures as the picture below.

Comment: @EmmanuelGNOFAM. Your post was not specific `But the data does not come in a good format to be displayed by ggplot`.

Comment: i am looking for a way to post the screenshot of what appears on my screen with geom-line

Comment: @EmmanuelGNOFAM. I don't find any screenshots of plots in your post

Comment: yes. i didn't find a way to attach the screenshot here. sorry

Comment: @EmmanuelGNOFAM. I showedd another option with `matplot` May be you needd that

Comment: thanks for helping me. I use to try each solution members posts here. this one works for me: df<- melt(df, id.vars = "ID") and  df[order(df$Id),]